# Subversion checkout not working in terminal over HTTPS Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ssl, svn, https, ubuntu-16.04

I am facing an issue while trying to checkout a project on the server using "svn co" command. Checking out and updating with softwares like TortoiseSVN or PHPStorm work properly over HTTPS, only the terminal wont work. I have set up previously similar servers but never with https support. I am using a Positive SSL that i have set up over ISPConfig 3.1 for the domain in question. While trying to check out the project with the following command:

```
svn co --username myusername https://example.com/svn/project /var/www/project
```

I get the following error:

```
   svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL https://example.com/svn/project
    svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication
```

The svn project and the folder where the project should go are set to chown www-data.

My dav_svn.conf containes the following:

```
<Location /svn/>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  SSLRequireSSL
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>
 </Location>
```

Don't know if software like clamav or similar can cause this problems like blocking the communication?

My svn version information is as follows:

```
svn, version 1.9.3 (r1718519)
   compiled Aug 10 2017, 16:59:15 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2015 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.8 (compiled with 1.3.8)
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

The following authentication credential caches are available:

* Plaintext cache in /root/.subversion
* Gnome Keyring
* GPG-Agent
* KWallet (KDE)

System information:

* running on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (xenial) [Linux 4.4.0-93-generic]
* linked dependencies:
  - APR 1.5.2 (compiled with 1.5.2)
  - APR-Util 1.5.4 (compiled with 1.5.4)
  - Expat 2.1.0 (compiled with 2.1.0)
  - SQLite 3.11.0 (compiled with 3.11.0)
  - Utf8proc 1.1.5 (compiled with 1.1.5)
  - ZLib 1.2.8 (compiled with 1.2.8)
```

Comment: Are you sure that SVN/Apache server and SVN client versions are up to date?

Comment: I am pretty sure since the install was made 3 days ago using the latest repos and isntalled all updates since then that came out for ubuntu, but in case that they are not how can i check ?

Comment: For the client, run `svn --version -v` and show the output, please.

Comment: Updated my post with the svn info.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my side while trying to checkout a github repository running a svn client 1.8.x using https. After investigating a bit, I discovered that it seems that the serf 1.3.8 can cause issues in certain cases.

By going back to a SVN client version 1.7.X the problem was solved on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I was trying to use **svnsync** to mirror a remote repository to local machine. The remote server is running SVN 1.5.1 and my local SVN is 1.10.2.

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL https://example.com/svn/project
svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication
```

I got my issue solved by upgrading Apache reverse proxy server that is in front of the SVN server. Probably the old Apache was using old SSL/TLS protocols/ciphers and newer SVN client refused connect. The proxy server needed upgrade anyways, so I didn't spend too much time checking configurations of the old proxy.

Comment: SVN 1.5.1 on server side? Upgrade httpd and svn.

Comment: Yeah, well I wanted to make backups of the repositories before I attempt any upgrades...